# The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it in django

Tags: django

**productscreate.html**

```
<form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
       
        <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Title:
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" data-bind="value: title"></td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:
        <textarea name="description" id="description">Description</textarea></td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image:
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image"></td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><button type="submit" id="submit" data-bind="submit: mySubmit">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script>
  
  var formData1 = new FormData();
  $(document).on('click', '#submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var viewModel = {
    title:ko.observable(),description:ko.observable(),
        mySubmit : function(formElement) {
            var formData = {
                'title' : viewModel.title() ,
                'description'  : viewModel.description(),
            };
            formData1.append('image',  $('#image')[0].files[0])
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{% url "productscreate" %}',
            data: formData,formData1,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            contentType: false,
            success: function (){
                window.location = '{% url "productslist" %}'; 
            },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                console.log(xhr.status + ":" + xhr.responseText)
            } 
            });
        }
    };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
 
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductsList(ListView):
     model = products
     context_object_name = 'products'
     template_name = "productslist.html"  
    

class ProductsCreate(CreateView):
    model = products
    fields = ['title','description','image']
    template_name = "productscreate.html"     
    success_url=reverse_lazy('productslist')


class ProductsDetailView(DetailView):
     template_name = "productsdetail.html"
     queryset = products.objects.all()
     context_object_name = 'products'
     model = products
```

**models.py**

```
class products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

**productsdetail.html**

```
  <form>

      
      
     Title:- {{products.title }} <br><br>
     
     Description:- {{ products.description}}<br><br>

 
     Image :- <img src="{{products.image.url}}" alt="image"><br><br>

     

 

     <button><a href="/edit/{{ products.id}}">Edit</a></button>
    </form>
```

Image is not displaying in detail products page It shows  The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it in detail page.
When i create a product image is not displaying I have given ajax code also
Please help me to solve this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you storing the image, did you check the image is present at `/static/images/` location.

Comment: Yes I checked but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much i have understand you are not able to upload imaage from the frontend is you are having  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action ="">
      {% csrf_token %}
       
        <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Title:
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" data-bind="value: title"></td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:
        <textarea name="description" id="description">Description</textarea></td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image:
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image"></td>
        <br>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><button type="submit" id="submit" data-bind="submit: mySubmit">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

i belive you have configure your staticfiles and media files perfectly this should work

Comment: then mark it as correct answer it will help other

Comment: How to do image in ajax ..because without using ajax also image is working I want to do form with ajax Now when i remove ajax code then also image is working how to do this with ajax

Comment: i dont understand what you want to explain what do you mean by doing image with ajax

Comment: This site is not working

Comment: ping me on the link there let me understand your problem

Comment: This link is not working

Comment: do you have telegram installed

Comment: please give ur correct mail id

Comment: sarangkkl2@gmail.com that email was also correct

Comment: I send the mail

Comment: not received still why dont you give email

Comment: ranjuranjitha.97@yahoo.com please send a mail

Comment: done i have sended

Comment: this answer is not correct and not resolving the problem

Answer (score 1):

It means that for that product, there is no image, so the `ImageField` is `NULL`. You thus should check if there is an image with:

```
{% if products.image %}
    Image :- <img src="{{products.image.url}}" alt="image"><br><br>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I checked this code it is also not working there is no error but image is not displaying

Comment: @RanjithaSanker: that's because for that product there *is* no image. Since the database has no image, there is no image you can show.

Comment: I created a product with image using ajax and html but image is not saving in database what is the issue

Comment: When i create a product image is not create in database what is the issue in this code..I think some issue in productcreate html page in ajax code